# By using $http in angularjs can we write error or exception messages in text file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question:** How to write error/exception messages in text file {No jQuery Solution}

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to call a logging service on the server to write to text file. You don't have access to the file system via javascript (unless you're running javascript on the server, like node.js etc.).

[Log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) is one example of framework that gives you the ability to log on the server via javascript.

Comment: Hi kjell, Earlier I am using log4js but its not writing error messages in a text file. Error and warning messages are display only log4js framework and i want to store these messages in a .txt or .jsp file

Answer (score 0):

please check this code and run the code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="AppController">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>
        Logging Client-Side Errors With AngularJS And Stacktrace.js
    </title>

    <style type="text/css">

        a[ ng-click ] {
            cursor: pointer ;
            text-decoration: underline ;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>
        Logging Client-Side Errors With AngularJS And Stacktrace.js
    </h1>

    <p>
        <a ng-click="causeError()">Cause Error</a>...
    </p>

    <p>
        <em>
            <strong>Note:</strong> Look at the JavaScript console to
            see the errors being reported.
        </em>
    </p>



    <!-- Load jQuery and AngularJS from the CDN. -->
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="../../vendor/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="../../vendor/angularjs/angular-1.0.7.min.js">
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="../../vendor/stacktrace/stacktrace-min-0.4.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        // Create an application module for our demo.
        var app = angular.module( "Demo", [] );


        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //


        // The "stacktrace" library that we included in the Scripts
        // is now in the Global scope; but, we don't want to reference
        // global objects inside the AngularJS components - that's
        // not how AngularJS rolls; as such, we want to wrap the
        // stacktrace feature in a proper AngularJS service that
        // formally exposes the print method.
        app.factory(
            "stacktraceService",
            function() {

                // "printStackTrace" is a global object.
                return({
                    print: printStackTrace
                });

            }
        );


        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //


        // By default, AngularJS will catch errors and log them to
        // the Console. We want to keep that behavior; however, we
        // want to intercept it so that we can also log the errors
        // to the server for later analysis.
        app.provider(
            "$exceptionHandler",
            {
                $get: function( errorLogService ) {

                    return( errorLogService );

                }
            }
        );


        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //


        // The error log service is our wrapper around the core error
        // handling ability of AngularJS. Notice that we pass off to
        // the native "$log" method and then handle our additional
        // server-side logging.
        app.factory(
            "errorLogService",
            function( $log, $window, stacktraceService ) {

                // I log the given error to the remote server.
                function log( exception, cause ) {

                    // Pass off the error to the default error handler
                    // on the AngualrJS logger. This will output the
                    // error to the console (and let the application
                    // keep running normally for the user).
                    $log.error.apply( $log, arguments );

                    // Now, we need to try and log the error the server.
                    // --
                    // NOTE: In production, I have some debouncing
                    // logic here to prevent the same client from
                    // logging the same error over and over again! All
                    // that would do is add noise to the log.
                    try {

                        var errorMessage = exception.toString();
                        var stackTrace = stacktraceService.print({ e: exception });

                        // Log the JavaScript error to the server.
                        // --
                        // NOTE: In this demo, the POST URL doesn't
                        // exists and will simply return a 404.
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "./javascript-errors",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: angular.toJson({
                                errorUrl: $window.location.href,
                                errorMessage: errorMessage,
                                stackTrace: stackTrace,
                                cause: ( cause || "" )
                            })
                        });

                    } catch ( loggingError ) {

                        // For Developers - log the log-failure.
                        $log.warn( "Error logging failed" );
                        $log.log( loggingError );

                    }

                }


                // Return the logging function.
                return( log );

            }
        );


        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //


        // I control the root of the application.
        app.controller(
            "AppController",
            function( $scope ) {

                // ---
                // PUBLIC METHODS.
                // ---


                // I cause an error to be thrown in nested functions.
                $scope.causeError = function() {

                    foo();

                };


                // ---
                // PRIVATE METHODS.
                // ---


                function bar() {

                    // NOTE: "y" is undefined.
                    var x = y;

                }


                function foo() {

                    bar();

                }

            }
        );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But i do not want to use jquery

Comment: please kindly refer following url it may be help to you!!!                                http://tech.zumba.com/2014/08/02/angularjs-forget-jquery/

Comment: but in this url they are not storing error messages in text file

Comment: Hi kjell,
Earlier I am using log4js but its not writing error messages in a text file. Error and warning messages are display only log4js framework and i want to store these messages in a .txt or .jsp file